# CSS keyframe amimation on pseudo elements not working in Webkit?

Tags: css, animation, webkit, keyframe

I found some posts around here about this topic and they always point to css-tricks.com. Most notabely http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-animationstransitions-bug-fixed-in-webkit/#comment-1166310 in which the autor states that those koind of animations are working in webkit since Jan 2013.
There is an example provided (http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/BkhFI) that does exactly what I would like to do with keyframe animation.

But while this works fine in Firefox, it does not work in Chrome 32, Windows and Chrome Android.

What am I missing about webkit (not?) supporting those keyframe animations? What has changed over the last year?

Any other ideas on getting this kind of animation working in webkit?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "doesn't work in..Windows"...works for me in chrome on windows 7

Comment: Ok, I open the codepen in Chrome. I see the code and below the preview. In the preview there are two "Frames" with a thick red bar on the left in each. The lower one moves across when I hover on the frame. The upper one does not animate at all. Compared with firefox, there the upper red bar is animated immediately.